# Obj-C - Display emoji in UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, emoji

I've configured MySQL tables to store emojis with the following:

```
ALTER TABLE field_data_field_notes MODIFY field_notes_value 
VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

That said, when I return strings to my app and try to display them in a UILabel, they appear like this:

```
Birthday emoji &amp;#x1F388;
```

The emoji is a balloon. I've tried the below code to decode it and display the actual emoji, but it doesn't seem to work (e.g. the UILabel still displays the emoji &amp text)? **Note**, I'm using Drupal and I have the 'Unicode' module enabled, so I imagine this is why the encoded format is &#x1F388.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        
 TimeTableViewCell *cell = (TimeTableViewCell *)[self.subtableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:WeeklyTableIdentifier];
                
                    
                if (cell == nil)
                {
                    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TimeTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
                    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
                    
                }
    
    NSString *encodedString =[self.sortedByTime valueForKey:@"notes"][indexPath.row];
    
    NSString *decodedString = [self decodeString:encodedString];
    
                      
    cell.notes.text = decodedString;
    
    }


- (NSString *)decodeString:(NSString *)string {
    // Decode HTML entities
    NSDictionary *entities = @{
        @"&amp;" : @"&",
        @"&quot;" : @"\"",
        @"&apos;" : @"'",
        @"&lt;" : @"<",
        @"&gt;" : @">",
        // Add more entity mappings as needed
    };

    NSMutableString *decodedString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:string];
    
    for (NSString *entity in entities) {
        NSString *replacement = [entities objectForKey:entity];
        [decodedString replaceOccurrencesOfString:entity withString:replacement options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [decodedString length])];
    }
    
    // Decode Unicode escape sequences
    NSString *decodedUnicodeString = [decodedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#x" withString:@"\\U0000"];
    NSData *data = [decodedUnicodeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *decodedEmojiString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
    
    return decodedEmojiString ?: decodedString;
}
```

Here is the code I'm using to save the string to my database:

```
NSDictionary *notesField = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.notesField.text, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
 NSDictionary *notesFieldcontent = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notesField] forKey:@"und"];
            
            [self.nodeData setObject:notesFieldcontent forKey:@"field_notes"];
    
      [DIOSNode nodeSave:self.nodeData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
               
    
      } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                
                
             
            }];
```

Comment: It would likely help if you stepped back and started with the code you use to store the string containing the emoji in the database and the code to read it back out. It seems odd that you end up with a need to decode HTML entities. That indicates to me that there is an issue with the code that stores and/or retrieves the data to/from the database.

Comment: See updated question :) Hope that provides more context! @HangarRash

Comment: Not really. The problem is likely with the code that either sends the string to the database or retrieves the string from the database. If your Objective-C iOS app is sending a normal `NSString` then your Objective-C iOS code should receive a normal `NSString`. No encoding should be needed.

Comment: How strange - see updated again. This time I've included the code I'm using to save my string to the database (the string I use for testing is just the word Birthday with a balloon emoji in the self.notesField.text field). @HangarRash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a super simple solution to my question. Posting it here incase anyone else runs into it. My original data string that was returned:

```
Birthday emoji &amp;#x1F388;
```

Here's the code I ended up using to make the emoji appear in my UILabel.

**ViewController.m**

```
 NSString *htmlEntity = [self.finalTimes valueForKey:@"notes"][indexPath.row];
 NSString *replacementString = [htmlEntity stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"amp;" withString:@""];

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   
               
      NSData *data = [replacementString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
             
      UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Oblique" size:11.0];
               UIColor *textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor]; // Set the correct font name and size
               NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor};
               NSMutableAttributedString *styledAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:attributedString];
               [styledAttributedString addAttributes:attributes range:NSMakeRange(0, styledAttributedString.length)];

               cell.notes.attributedText = styledAttributedString;
               
               
              });
```